# Calling multiple functions inside for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, for-loop

I am working in node js express framework and I have a scenario where I have to call 2-3 nested callback functions inside for loop.
Below is my code:

```
for (i in jdp_tb_trades) {
  var jdp_response_json_parsed = JSON.parse(jdp_tb_trades[i].jdp_response);
    processConsign(jdp_tb_trades[i].tid, function(err_process_consign, lpnumber) {
        if (err_process_consign) {
          console.log("Some error occurred in processConsign. Error is:" + err_process_consign);
          //Check if generate XML is enabled from admin end.
          configuration.getOneByKey('generateXml', function(err_configuration, result_configuration) {
              if (err_configuration) {
                console.log('[generateXml]: generate xml enabled/disabled - No response.');
                return callback(null, lpnumber);
              } else {
                if (result_configuration.value == 'true') {
                  console.log('[generateXml]: generate xml enabled.')
                  generateXml(jdp_tb_trades[i].tid, jdp_response_json_parsed, lpnumber, function(err_generate_xml, success_generate_xml);
                    if (err_generate_xml) {
                      return callback(err_generate_xml);
                    } else {
                      return callback(null, success_generate_xml);
                    }
                  });
              } else {
                console.log('[generateXml]: generate xml disabled.');
                return callback(null, lpnumber);
              }
            }
          });
      } else {

        //Check if generate XML is enabled.
        configuration.getOneByKey(
          'generateXml',
          function(err_configuration, result_configuration) {
            if (err_configuration) {
              console.log('[generateXml]: generate xml enabled/disabled - No response.');
              return callback(null, lpnumber);
            } else {
              if (result_configuration.value == 'true') {
                console.log('[generateXml]: generate xml enabled.')
                generateXml(jdp_tb_trades[i].tid, jdp_response_json_parsed, lpnumber, function(err_generate_xml, success_generate_xml) {
                  if (err_generate_xml) {
                    return callback(err_generate_xml);
                  } else {
                    return callback(null, success_generate_xml);
                  }

                });
              } else {
                console.log('[generateXml]: generate xml disabled.');
                return callback(null, lpnumber);
              }
            }
          });

    });
}
```

**Update**
The above code is part of a function named *getOrders* which is called as:

```
module.exports = {
    getOrders: function (callback) {
        getOrders(function(err_getOrders, getOrdersResponse){
            if(err_getOrders){
                console.log("generate Order process error:"+err_getOrders);
                return callback(err_getOrders);
            }
            else{
                console.log("generate Order process success:"+getOrdersResponse);
                return callback(null, getOrdersResponse);
            }
        });
    },
}
```

I have made multiple callbacks because function ends in multiple scenarios. I am not concerned about output of getOrders because I am not going to consume that output anywhere.

Here I have two functions processConsign and generateXml. generateXml is called in callback of processConsign. But I think forloop does not wait for these two tasks to get complete and keep increment the loop without waiting for processing of these two functions.

Is there any way by which I can make for loop wait for completion of these two processes and then executing the next loop?

Comment: you are expecting an Array for ___getOrdersResponse___ `in return callback(null, getOrdersResponse);` ?

Comment: @kiro112 No I am not expecting any array here. I just want some output. It might be string. So that I can know the process has been executed properly.

Comment: hmm. but in this case you have a multiple response(loop). but base on above you only want a single response ?

Comment: Yes. After all callback will be excuted once for every loop. or I can keep appending my output of each loop and call callback once and send response once.

Comment: please check the update

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [async.each](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each)

```
    async.each(jdp_tb_trades, (jdp_tb_trade, callback) => {
        // do manipulation here
        // return callback() after the process. pass err if error
    }, loop_ended (err) => {
        if (err) {
            // Error in loop | err callback returned with err
        }
        // loop already ended here
    });
```

Kindly check this
        const async = require('async');

```
    function getOrders (callback) {
        async.each(jdp_tb_trades, generate_xml, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                // the callback return err using callback(err)
            }
            else {
                // check the jdp_tb_trades. no error found
            }
        });
    }

    function generate_xml (jdp_tb_trade, callback) {
        let jdp_response_json_parsed; 

        try {
            jdp_response_json_parsed = JSON.parse(jdp_tb_trade.jdp_response);
        } catch (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        processConsign(jdp_tb_trade.tid, (err_process_consign, lpnumber) => {

            if (err_process_consign) {
                console.log(`Some error occurred in processConsign. Error is: ${err_process_consign}`);

                //Check if generate XML is enabled from admin end.
                configuration.getOneByKey('generateXml', (err_configuration, result_configuration) => {
                    if (err_configuration) {
                        console.log('[generateXml]: generate xml enabled/disabled - No response.');

                        // base on your callback it still a success response
                        // return callback(null, lpnumber);

                        jdp_tb_trade.lpnumber = lpnumber;
                        return callback();
                    }
                    else {
                        if (result_configuration.value == 'true') {
                            console.log('[generateXml]: generate xml enabled.')
                            generateXml(jdp_tb_trade.tid, jdp_response_json_parsed, lpnumber, (err_generate_xml, success_generate_xml) => {
                                if (err_generate_xml) {
                                    jdp_tb_trade.err_generate_xml = err_generate_xml;

                                    // return error
                                    return callback(err_generate_xml);
                                } else {
                                    jdp_tb_trade.success_generate_xml = success_generate_xml;

                                    return callback();
                                    // return callback(null, success_generate_xml);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log('[generateXml]: generate xml disabled.');
                            return callback(null, lpnumber);
                        }
                    }
                });          
            }
            else {
                if (result_configuration.value == 'true') {
                    console.log('[generateXml]: generate xml enabled.')
                    generateXml(jdp_tb_trades[i].tid, jdp_response_json_parsed, lpnumber, (err_generate_xml, success_generate_xml) => {
                        if (err_generate_xml) {
                            return callback(err_generate_xml);
                        } else {
                            jdp_tb_trade.success_generate_xml = success_generate_xml;
                            // return callback(null, success_generate_xml);
                            return callback();
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    console.log('[generateXml]: generate xml disabled.');
                    jdp_tb_trade.lpnumber = lpnumber;
                    return callback();

                    // return callback(null, lpnumber);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: wll async.each ensure that my function execute after that my loop will increment?

Comment: it should work. but you need to adjust your implementation because you are returning different callback, can you share how you call this function ?
because async.each can only modify function and return error but not return multiple callback

Comment: I have made an update in my question. I am making multiple callbacks where ever function ends.

Comment: I could not understand your updated solution kiro. You have